# Build CocoaPods into single library

Tags: swift, xcode, build, cocoapods, xcodebuild

I want to build my CocoaPods libraries into single library (or even multiple will also be OK) in order to:

> 1. Freeze pod libraries versions
> 2. Reduce build server build time (building libraries takes a lot of time)

Is there a way to build **CocoaPods libraries** into 1 or several static libraries and link them to my project?

Comment: Would that not be the way you would do it without pods? Point one is easy to fix, just use fixed versions in your podfile. Point two is a little harder.. you could try not cleaning everything before each integration. If you still want the setup you are talking about you will need to include all .a and headers in your version control system so your build server gets everything when it clones the repo. Or are you looking for a way to include .a files in your Podfile? I think it can be done but i don't think it has any benefits from including it directly in your project.

Comment: Yes, I want to add all headers and .a files into my repository and just update them when I need it manually. Not cleaning everything before building on build server is bad idea, since incremental building is buggy. The question is how can I build Pods separately (preferably into one library) and how can I link my project correctly with this library

Comment: If you are using third party pods the, if you check there git site, the usually have a prebuilt library you can download. I would suggest you get rid of the Pods altogether then since running pod install modifies your project setup. If you can't find a prebuilt library just checkout the code and build it yourself.

Comment: My decision was to build all pods into frameworks